# wordpress wp-admin redirect

Tags: mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a site using localhost.  Some where I have messed up a setting and when I try to open my wp-admin site it is putting localhost at the beginning of my path names.

ex.  when I try to go to localhost/wp-admin it redirects me to http://localhost/wp-admin/localhost/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

I have tried renaming .htaccess file, updating siteurl & home tables in phpmyadmin back to localhost.

Comment: go in wordpress options table and look for siteurl and home, see if they are http://localhost, @AdamSeymoad

Comment: They are.  That was the first thing that I tried.

Comment: There are a few other things that are happening too.  I noticed on some of my image paths it is appending localhost to the front of the path as well when trying to echo the stylesheet path.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem yesterday just after installing Wordpress. Check in your host cPanel if **varnish caching** has been enabled. If so, go ahead and disable it. Wait for 30 minutes and then try logging in.

Answer (score 0):

It look like in DB siteurl & home tables site URL added 2 times by mistake. review that table again.

Answer (score 0):

For me i had 127.0.0.1 local.se set in /etc/hosts and in my DB siteurl & home tables local.se it was supposed to be http://local.se

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after I installed WordPress. what i did to fix this problem was; i opened `wp-config.php` and realized that the code below was added at the end of it. that is immediately after `require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';`

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         'Uzmcd+VBAcxAzfaOv8ugAibvDuWDdXjbrJxsIz+0CwiQPEnW6mccVP/BA4qANztIaHNEK/RObNYI3/blcY0RBQ==');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'v3Lz27eRYP4YjS9ywi0CrZ6InaiScQgY1F7sfNTOjjL0fN0IjT/XH2M5zXeyQ7kF/5TdqdLqomeag9xnMO31mA==');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'OiUQWMkLNtpTx5Q5laD8YRucn6RWba2utVdOhXM6QgpK28ovKocUBAQvO2ae7Q0ldmyZ92SEywOD/ZO73AZCmA==');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '0D2HmcjWoHFlHW5Lmqsl2SixfrrnAOKk3cb3lIUucqcWktVdHsUSxqOr48t8uOEKUquZ25w8W5ipCMkuwDHcvw==');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'bkcMUiz15QYph3ZRT9HM3j6qPLkztDNncjASNKzIEibeAyqOF/exuv5VFj+4DStbTnaAu2lGSAmW6ZC5y21kog==');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'ba+wEETlohHP0wHli5GFVbIgjPzOyXxkqofzddgfdRv678x0qhJLC4sZyMEDBDqpzWkWHyev57/m2ueThsoPjQ==');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'SxlJM5p0sOGY9DidGYbVcfv6AaMEA5jB1am+2o+c5Rd99bZd5GwA3xrFluRb2zbk/v7Px9PAbCflWdp5KZKmyA==');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'CLfNEb7uE+0CGnItMSq5xy7+1MxGxUuaI1mxWp1J2AHYP4UitJwM5ugJO14GGTyhWoTujaJ7acp/tm8Et+LsDQ==');
```

So i just deleted it and everything was fine